How to get an Ether frame in bytes
I am capturing a single package using scapy:
from scapy.all import *

while True:
    data = sniff(iface = 'lo', count = 1)

Then I try to convert the resulting object into bytes:
print(raw(data))

And I'm getting an error:
TypeError: 'Ether' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
I need to capture a packet and store it in a variable as bytes.
I tried it this way:
from scapy.all import *

while True:
    data = sniff(iface = 'lo', count = 1)
    print(raw(data))

and this:
from scapy.all import *

while True:
    data = sniff(iface = 'lo', count = 1,  prn = lambda x: raw(x))
    print(data)


I believe it is because sniff returns a list of packet objects. Access the one you need via list indexing, in your case raw(data[0]).

Thank you very much!
Everything works fine.
